# How to prove that $6n^2 + 20n \notin \Omega{(n^3)}$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, proof-explanation

I'm not sure how to go about this, I've tried finding constants and N values to find out, for instance I tried to prove it through contradiction but I must be doing something wrong because I'm getting something that cannot be possible. This is one such example that I tried:

$N = 1 , c = 1$

but this is what I get:

$6(1^2) + 20(1) \geq 0^3 $

$26 \geq 0$

which does the opposite. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since the $\Omega$ function refers to asymptotics, the first few cases don't matter.

If $n \ge 10$, then $n^3 > 6n^2 + 20n$. Proof: Since

$$6n + 20 \le 6n + 2n = 8 n < n \cdot n = n^2,$$

multiplying both sides by $n$ gives

$$6n^2 + 20n < n^3.$$

Note: $n \ge 9$ works too, but $n \ge 10$ is just slightly simpler to show.